# Web Deployment Project with an replacement .config geting "changed"

Tags: .net, asp.net, encryption, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I have cruisecontrol.net building a asp.net web deployment project. This is working great until i created multiple deployment "configurations". Basically we have a dev,test,stage, and prod.

The stage and prod configurations have a web.config replacement setup to change the plain text connectionstring section to what our production webservers use as the encrypted value.

The problem is after the build the resulting web.config has a different CipherValue that what was in our source control repository.

Is msbuild re-encrypting the connection strings during the build?

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the system described in [this MSDN article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2009/06/11/Encrypting-the-Web-Config-File.aspx), then the CipherValue will be different if it is generated on a different machine. But then they would also only be usable on that build server.